# Problem with lilypond upgrade on Debian "buster/sid"

Tags: debian, upgrade, dpkg

I have a problem with an uncompleted upgrade on my local Debian install:

```
  Operating System: Debian GNU/Linux buster/sid
            Kernel: Linux 4.12.0-1-686-pae
      Architecture: x86
```

I tried to fix it with `apt upgrade -f` and `dpkg --configure lilypond-data` but whatever I do, I get the following message:

```
Setting up lilypond-data (2.18.2-8) ...
 Running mktexlsr /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist...
mktexlsr: Updating /var/lib/texmf/ls-R-TEXLIVEDIST... 
mktexlsr: Done.
ln: failed to create symbolic link 'lilypond/user': File exists
dpkg: error processing package lilypond-data (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 lilypond-data
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

if I run `dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq --dry-run lilypond-data`
I get:

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent removal of lilypond-data:
 lilypond depends on lilypond-data (= 2.18.2-8).

dpkg: error processing package lilypond-data (--remove):
 dependency problems - not removing
Errors were encountered while processing:
 lilypond-data
```

Comment: Try : `sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq --dry-run lilypond-data`

Comment: @GAD3R THX, but unfortunately it did not work; I updated the question with the `terminal-output` for your suggested command.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The general approach would be to look at (shell script) `/var/lib/dpkg/info/lilypond-data.postinst` and find the `ln` line that's failing. Then determine why, and work around it (e.g., by `rm`ing the existing link, or worst case by editing the postinst). And of course then file a bug.

Except someone else has already done so—see [bug 871631](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=871631). And the bug has been fixed; you just need to grab (and install) 2.18.2-9 from unstable.

(Which yields an important lesson: check the bug tracking system before thinking about how to fix it...)

Also: you may want to install apt-listbugs.

Comment: THX, I grabbed `2.18.2-9` by adding unstable to `/etc/apt/sources.list` run `apt update` and upgraded with `apt-get --only-upgrade install lilypond`, removed unstable from `/etc/apt/sources.list` updated again; done.

Comment: @nath It's probably easier to just download the packages from the Debian package pages.

Answer (score 3):

This part shows what is important:

```
ln: failed to create symbolic link 'lilypond/user': File exists
dpkg: error processing package lilypond-data (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
```

Your post-installation script failed. It is likely because it wasn't configured to handle its previous version in the stable correctly.

The debian packages have two components:

1. a file archive, it is quite ordinary `.tar.gz` (or any similar), extracted into the root directory
2. installation scripts, which run *before* and *after* the archive extraction.

Thus, a package install seems so:

1. the pre-installation scripts of the package run
2. the package archive is extracted into the root directory
3. the post-installation scripts run

Removal happens similarly, but with a pre-removal and a post-removal script.

In your case, a package upgrade happened, then the script call order is a little bit more complex, but not heavily.

From them, the post-install script of the new package couldn't run on some reason. Thus, it is already extracted on your system.

Because it is a devel distribution, it is not very hard thing to manually hotfix the problem.

Edit the old post-installation script.

```
vi /var/lib/dpkg/info/lilypond-data.postinst
```

Find, where it can't create that link, and let him allow it.

After that, run:

```
dpkg --configure -a
```

will do what you want. (If it doesn't succeed, don't worry, edit again and retry.)